# Android make listen onClickListener of disabled button

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I have implemented a button for toggle purpose of the app state.
But after disabling button(setEnabled(false)) I can not capture the click of button.

Is there any way to listen to the click of disabled button?

Comment: how can one click a disabled button?

Comment: Once disabled, it will stop listening for any clicks. That's the whole point of disabling something eh? ;-)

Comment: Seems pretty legit. Use `ToggleButton` instead, because once a button is disabled, it's not possible for a user to click it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a reason why the Android guys developed a **[ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)**.

You should be using a **ToggleButton** and ***not a normal standard Button*** to implement toggling operation.